# how to run test script in AWS device farm?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, ui-automation

iam a beginer in automation,
Iam trying to run my test script in AWS

> how to run the android test script in AWS device farm?

Answer (score 1):

This varies greatly depending on what platform you're trying to test. Are you testing an iOS app or Android app? Have you read through the docs at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/setting-up.html? Once you give us a little more info we can point you in the right direction.